# Share State to other component | pass data to other component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, state, react-props

hello I'm currently learning about React, and I'm confused about how to pass data or state to another component

i have Search Component like this

```
function Search(props) {
  const [ query, setQuery ] = useState("")
  const [ movie, setMovie ] = useState({})

  function searchHandler() {

    axios.get(`${api.url}SearchMovie/${api.key}/${query}`)
    .then(res => {
      setMovie(res.data.results)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })

  }

  return (
    <div className="search-input">
        <div class="input-group input-custom mb-3">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Search Movie"
            onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            value={query}
          />
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-primary"
            onClick={searchHandler}
          >
            Search
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

and also MainPage Component like this

```
function MainPage() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        <Search />
        <hr />
        <div className="content">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-4">
              <Card
                image="https://dbkpop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/weeekly_we_are_teaser_2_monday.jpg"
                title="Monday"
                description="Monday Weeekly Member"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-4">
              <Card
                image="https://dbkpop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/weeekly_we_are_teaser_2_monday.jpg"
                title="Monday"
                description="Monday Weeekly Member"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-4">
              <Card
                image="https://dbkpop.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/weeekly_we_are_teaser_2_monday.jpg"
                title="Monday"
                description="Monday Weeekly Member"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainPage;
```

the problem is, how to pass State (movie) from Search Component to MainPage Component. so that I can render the data to MainPage Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Data in React flows down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down), so you need to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

Hence, the `movie` state should be in scope of `MainPage`:

```
function MainPage() {
  const [ movie, setMovie ] = useState({})
  
  // Set query results with setMovie
  return <Search setMovie={setMovie} ... />
}

function Search(props) {

  function searchHandler() {
    axios.get(`${api.url}SearchMovie/${api.key}/${query}`)
    .then(res => {
      props.setMovie(res.data.results)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

  return (...);
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the answer. I think to share state between components can only use Context